¿Cómo detectar un mando a distancia en una app Android, programada por Python?
Estoy realizando una aplicación que va a ser usada en un monitor que usa Android, y la aplicación esta siendo desarrollada con Python, con ayuda de las librerías de KivyMD y Kivy, y esta siendo compilada con Buildozer. Dentro de la aplicación tengo mapeadas algunas teclas del teclado para moverme en la aplicación, además del mando, ya que al ser usada en un monitor, no va funcionar a través de una pantalla táctil. Dentro de la aplicación te mueves entre botones, a la izquierda o a la derecha.
El problema es que una vez compilada e instalada en el monitor el mando no funciona para moverse, por los botones como he dicho, con las flechas (left, right, OK o Enter) como lo haría en otras aplicaciones, en cambio con las teclas del teclado si lo hace.
He intentado mapear los keycodes que por defecto los mandos a distancia mandan, aquí dejo el código:
class MainApp(MDApp):
#Creacion e inicializacion
def build(self):
    Window.bind(on_key_down=self.on_key_down)
    self.theme_cls.theme_cls = "Dark"
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
    self.chrono = 0
    Builder.load_file('myapp.kv')
    return Ui()

Esta es la función que se ejecuta al inicio, y que empareja la función on_key_down de Android que detecta que botón se a pulsado y la iguala a mi función personalizada, que es esta:
    #Función que se ejecuta al presionar las teclas
def on_key_down(self, window, keycode, scancode, codepoint, modifiers):
    print("Key: ",keycode)

    #Movimiento
    if (keycode == 55 or keycode == 21 or keycode == 276):  # Tecla 7 (Izquierda) o tecla izquierda mando
        self.moveLeft()
    elif (keycode == 57 or keycode == 22 or keycode == 275):  # Tecla 9 (Derecha) o tecla derecha mando
        self.moveRight()
    elif (keycode == 56 or keycode == 66 or keycode == 13):  # Tecla 8 (Enter) o tecla enter mando
        self.enterButton()
    elif (keycode == 4 or keycode == 27): # Tecla atrás mando
        self.back()

A pesar de mapear todo, no funciona, no lo detecta ya que el print del keycode que esta para debuggear cuando se pulsa el mando no imprime nada, es decir, no se mete en la función. He preguntado a fabrica y me ha dicho que la app debería, sin necesidad de programar nada extra, funcionar con el mando.
Además la compilación de buildozer esta siendo realizada sin ningún permiso especial de Android, con el buildozer.spec que te genera por defecto, solo se han cambiado nombres e iconos.
